# How to cast the result type?

Tags: java, generics, maps

I am trying to calculate the average value in Map collections. Every Key has exactly one value. How can I cast entry.getValue() so that compiler does not show errors?

[image: Eclipse code]

Comment: Don't post pictures of code, post code. Do you know what kind of numbers your map contains, i.e. can you use `Map<String, Double>` instead or are you forced to use `? extends Number` as value type?

Answer (score 2):

If you are really forced to handle a map of type `Map<String, ? extends Number>` and not e.g. `Map<String, Double>`, you can call [`doubleValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue--) on the number instance to convert this number to a double (the result is not guaranteed to be exact and may have been rounded).

```java
public static double avg(final Map<String, ? extends Number> map) {
    double sum = 0d;
    for (final var entry : map.entrySet()) {
        sum += entry.getValue().doubleValue();
    }
    return sum / map.size();
}
```

But if you can change the signature of your method, I'd suggest that instead:

```java
public static double avg(final Map<String, Double> map) {
    double sum = 0d;
    for (final var entry : map.entrySet()) {
        sum += entry.getValue();
    }
    return sum / map.size();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for Your time.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
 sum = sum + entry.getValue().floatValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others already noted, you can just call `doubleValue` or `floatValue`.

You can also give the caller the opportunity to tell you how he wants you to get the value:

```java
    public static double avg(final Map<String, ? extends Number> map) {
        return avg(map, Number::doubleValue);
    }

    public static <T> double avg(final Map<String, ? extends T> map, ToDoubleFunction<? super T> toDoubleFunction) {
        double sum = 0d;
        for (final var entry : map.entrySet()) {
            sum += toDoubleFunction.applyAsDouble(entry.getValue());
        }
        return sum / map.size();
    }
```

You could also use the Streams API for that:

```java
    public static double avg(final Map<String, ? extends Number> map) {
        return avg(map, Number::doubleValue);
    }

    public static <T> double avg(final Map<String, ? extends T> map, ToDoubleFunction<? super T> toDoubleFunction) {
        return map.values().stream()
                .mapToDouble(toDoubleFunction)
                .average()
                .orElse(0.0);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for effort.